# Not able to login to argocd cli

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, argo

Argocd login

Is not working, I endup with below error.

```
abilash@LAPTOP-BOSTG8L5:~$ argocd login 10.111.252.193  --sso --loglevel debug
FATA[0040] dial tcp 10.111.252.193:443: operation was canceled
```

I am able to login to the ui using the kubenetes svc.

```
NAME                                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
argocd-applicationset-controller          ClusterIP   10.105.83.56     <none>        7000/TCP,8080/TCP            47h
argocd-dex-server                         ClusterIP   10.104.74.189    <none>        5556/TCP,5557/TCP,5558/TCP   47h
argocd-metrics                            ClusterIP   10.107.240.42    <none>        8082/TCP                     47h
argocd-notifications-controller-metrics   ClusterIP   10.109.142.245   <none>        9001/TCP                     47h
argocd-redis                              ClusterIP   10.105.210.237   <none>        6379/TCP                     47h
argocd-repo-server                        ClusterIP   10.104.196.224   <none>        8081/TCP,8084/TCP            47h
argocd-server                             ClusterIP   10.111.252.193   <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP               47h
argocd-server-metrics                     ClusterIP   10.108.32.131    <none>        8083/TCP                     47h
```

Help pls!!

Comment: I've had to add `--skip-test-tls` and `--grpc-web` to by login command to get it to work w/ SSO

Comment: Thanks for responding. Tried with 

argocd login 10.111.252.193  --sso --skip-test-tls --grpc-web --loglevel debug

But it is taking forever. Weird.

Comment: @LostJon Got the below error

FATA[0214] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Post "https://10.111.252.193:443/cluster.SettingsService/Get": dial tcp 10.111.252.193:443: connect: connection timed out

Comment: sounds like a Security Group issue in AWS.

Comment: But I have installed it in my local windows machine. . on WSL2 ubuntu

Comment: maybe some other firewall on your machine then? Do you need to specify `localhost` instead of your ip address? I dont know how you configured SSO to your local machine. Also, is it possible your IP address changes?

Answer (score 3):

Use below , works like a charm with classic loadbalancers.

```
argocd login your-argocd-server.com --skip-test-tls  --grpc-web
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this after upgrading from version `2.6.2` to `2.8.4`.

The command below should work:

```
argocd --port-forward --port-forward-namespace=argocd --grpc-web --plaintext login --username=admin --password=Your-Password
```

I personally used kubectl for port-forwarding, and following [this](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/11783) thread, the command I specified above should be used instead.